# How to check condition in one to many relation model filed value in jpa

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, playframework

I am using play framework(java) 1.2.4, jpa and hibernate.How can i check relation(oneToMany) model filed value on find error occurred

Contry model:

```
@Entity
public class Countries extends Model {

    @Required
    public String name;

    public String iso2;

    public String iso3; 

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="country", fetch=FetchType.EAGER,  cascade=CascadeType.All)
    public List<States> states;

    public Countries() { }

}
```

State model:

```
@Entity
public class States extends Model {

   @Required
   public long country_id;

   @Required
   public String name;  

   @Required
   public long product_id; 

   @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
   @NotFound(action = NotFoundAction.IGNORE)
   @JoinColumn(name="country_id", nullable=false,insertable=false, updatable=false)
   public Countries country;

   public States() { }
}
```

In Contry controller:

```
   List<Countries> countries = Countries.find("states.product_id =5").fetch();
```

When i check states table value (oneToMany) following error occurred:

```
    IllegalArgumentException occured : org.hibernate.QueryException: illegal attempt to dereference collection
```

Answer (score 0):

I think something like this will work, though it's untested.

```
List<Countries> countries = Countries.find(
    "select c from Countries c, States s where s.country = c and s.product_id = ?", 5
);
```

You might need quote around 5, I forget. You can also do it with a join clause, but I don't think that's necessary here.

Also, your model names should be singular, not plural. That should confuse you. It confuses me :-)

Answer (score 0):

Method `find` supports also normal JPQL queries. Following is drop-in replacement for fetching unique list of countries that do have state with product_id 5:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(s.country) FROM States s WHERE s.product_id = 5
```